# set the last bin of histogram to a interval between a number and infinity in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a really skewed data and I am want to set my histogram's last bin to include a threshold number to infinity so that my histogram will be not skewed. I know we can set `xlim` or `coord_cartisian` to zooming but I want to keep all the data.

```
x=data.frame(100*rbeta(10000,2,50))
ggplot(data=x,aes(x))+geom_histogram(bins=20)+scale_x_continuous(breaks =seq(1,100,by=5))
```

[image]

Comment: Use `geom_histogram(breaks=c(...))` to set customised bins, where `c(...)` is the vector of values you want.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Do I have to typed all the customized bins? All I need is just same bin size for all but the last one. I used to just typed by hand and plus a inf, is there an easier way?

Comment: You could do something like `c(seq(from=1,to=10,by=1),11,100000)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `geom_histogram(breaks=c(...))` to set customised bins, where `c(...)` is the vector of values you want.  For example `c(seq(from=1,to=11,by=1),100000)`

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer will get a little ugly if the [aggreagted bin gets too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q16I8.png). You can map the values:

```
x <- mapvalues(x,
              from = c(aggBinLow:aggBinHigh),
              to = c(rep.int(aggBinLow,aggBinHigh-aggBinLow+1)))
```

and add a [scale with distinct values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5tPP.png):

```
g +
 scale_x_continuous(breaks=min:aggBinLow,labels=c(sprintf("%s",min:aggBinLow-1),">aggBinLow-1"))
```